# Adding an auto-generated number in table row in asciidoc file

Tags: asciidoc

Hi so I want to add "auto-generated" row number into a table in asciidoc file. I have something like this.

```
.Sample Table
[cols=2, options="header"]
|===
|ID | Description

|1
|This is row #1

|2
|This is row #2

|===
```

Where 1 and 2 are hardcoded. Is there a way to make them auto-generated? Like how we can have "." in list view to become numbers.

Thanks,
KT.

Comment: Note that in general, (data) tables don't have an intrinsic order: one should be able to swap rows (or columns) without changing the actual data. Using auto-generated row numbers defeats that purpose, since swapping rows would then actually alter the data in that auto-numbered column. Even if this future would exist, I wouldn't use it. (In the example given, consider swapping the two rows while using auto-generated numbers. Now it would say something nonsensical like `|<1>|This is row #2 \n\n |<2>|This is row #1`, with `<#>` indicating a  generated number.)

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `{counter}` attribute. [Here's a tutorial.](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/09/awesome-asciidoctor-use-counters-in.html)